# Excel / VBA: How to set FormatCondition.NumberFormat to the special Variant value "Empty"?

Tags: vba, excel, conditional-formatting

When I create a new conditional format in Excel manually (using the standard dialogs), the default NumberFormat is unset.  This implies: "Do not override the number format when applying a conditional format."  When I poke at the conditional format object in the VBA debugger, `FormatCondition.NumberFormat` has the special `Variant` value `Empty`.

When I create a new conditional format using VBA via `Range.FormatConditions.Add`, the default NumberFormat is "General".  Using VBA, when I try to set `FormatCondition.NumberFormat` to the special `Variant` value `Empty`, the code runs (does not throw error), but the result is `;;`.  That is very different from `Empty`.

1. Does this occur in later versions of Excel?  (I don't have access to try.)
2. Is there a workaround for this problem?

To clarify: Excel ranges (and cells) may have two number formats.  The first is the base number format, set using `Ctrl+1`.  This is exclusive of conditional formatting.  The second is the conditional format number format.  If set, and the format condition is triggered, this second number format will override the base number format.

If this matters: I am using Excel 2010 (14.x) on Windows 7.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand. If the number format has been set in Conditional formatting then the second number format `will` override the base number format. And if the condition is not true then the base format stays as it is...

Answer (score 0):

That's interesting. However, I notice that it doesn't actually change the appearance of my numbers. Before and after running a macro, and seeing the change to General, my plain numbers, currency and dates still look the same.

Also, note that a format of General is equivalent to clearing the Custom box in the Format Cells dialog. In VBA it's equivalent to:

```
Activecell.NumberFormat = ""
```

or even:

```
Activecell.NumberFormat = vbNullString
```

In other words, it's pretty empty.

Comment: Perhaps my explanation is unclear.  Try setting number format in active cell to something like: `+#,##0.00;-#,##0.00;0.00`.  Then you will see the difference between `General` and your number format.

Comment: So, I set the number 2.342 to the format you list here. Then I run some code - generated by the macro recorder - to apply some conditional formatting. Both before and after the number displayed in the cell is 2.34. I'm also running Excel 2010 on Win 7.

Comment: Hopefully it's clear that I find this an interesting question. If you care to post a more step-by-step example of what you're doing and seeing, I'll definitely check it out.

Comment: Thanks for your interest.  I do appreciate.  I will try to add precise steps to recreate this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Having the same result, I tried to set the `NumberFormat` of `FormatCondition` to the same value as the cell number format:

```
MyCell.FormatConditions(1).NumberFormat = MyCell.NumberFormat
```

It generated an error that had the consequence to empty the format condition number format (just what I wanted)

So I finally tried this and it solved my problem:

```
On Error Resume Next
MyCell.FormatConditions(1).NumberFormat = "this does not exist"
Err.clear
On Error GoTo 0   'or any error handling you already set
```